# What quest is the object Dravin's Bow from?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So apparently I've found a quest item `Dravin's Bow` somewhere in my travels. Anyone found this quest, since I can't drop the item, I'd like to complete it quick-fastly, as I subscribe to the 'pick up everything that's not nailed down' school of thought.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you picked up was a miscellaneous objective, *Bow to the Master* when you were in the Ratway Warrens.

To complete it, return the bow to Dravin. You can find him at the Merryfair Farm.

Comment: After the dragon murdering Dravin the first time... was finally able to get this out of my inventory. Thanks.

Comment: Just make sure you dont pick up the only N'Gasta!... (though it was so popular in Morrowind) as you'll never be able to get id of the 1lb if you don't talk to Ugrub first.

Comment: @Curtis, this is a fallacy. Quest objects do not actually weigh anything.

Answer (score 18):

You can also put it on any weapon display if you own a home and don't feel like doing quest yet.

Comment: Just tested this, I was very surprised to see it work. Thanks for the tip, but honestly I just want it out of my house. Regardless, +1 for completeness.

Answer (score 15):

He is in MerryFair Farm directly west from riften stables, However if he is already dead (like it was for me) Then **you can just place the bow on his body** and take whatever you want as a reward from his corpse - I only took half his gold, im not greedy you know :)

Comment: note to self...

Answer (score 3):

You can give it back to Dravin, a guy in a farm near the `Goldenglow Estate` (an island where you have to go for a quest for the Guild of Thieves)

Actually I'm not sure if the guy is called Dravin. It is an elf working in a farm in front of the island where Goldenglow is.

Answer (score 3):

This bow is part of the quest [Bow to the Master](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Bow_to_the_Master).  Take the bow to Dravin Llanith at [Merryfair Farm](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Merryfair_Farm) to trade it for some gems.

If Draven's dead, you're stuck with the bow unless you're playing on the PC and can remove it via the console command:

```
player.removeitem 0006b9ad 1
```

Bug - PC- Completing the quest removes the bow but not it's weight. PC users can do this anyway after completing the quest (successfully or not) to solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

There's a dark elf named Dravin Llanith  at the MerryFair farm outside of Riften. He's normally feeding chickens a little ways from the house.

Comment: What does this answer add that hasn't been said over 2 years ago?

Comment: Didn't look at the date.