# Where is Draven and how do I return his bow? I can't find him anywhere

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What quest is the object Dravin's Bow from?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35871/what-quest-is-the-object-dravins-bow-from)

I found this bow which I can't get out of my inventory. It supposedly belongs to Draven, but I have no idea where he is. Can someone tell me and or how to start that quest?

Comment: sorry for the duplicate question. I try and do a thorough search, I even just searched his name and it didn't come up. Is there a way for me to do/perform better searches?